# How to use Ios UI Automation xpath in appium for ios

Tags: appium, ios-ui-automation, appium-ios

I am using iosuiautomator for finding the xpath of element

[image]

(Note: In appium can't find the xpath). while running following error is displaying

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using iOSUIAutomation search strategy, you don't need `localTarget().target.().etc`. You can start from right after `mainWindow()`. I also noticed you put the tap action inside the quotes but is actually a function of the mobile element (and has 2 parameters) so what you'd want is:

`driver.findElementByIosUIAutomation(".tableViews()[2].cells()[2]").tap(1, 250)`

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your response. Actually I am new to appium . Getting error as "The method tap(int, int) is undefined for the type WebElement" while using above code. @econoMichael

Comment: Your driver should be initialized as `IOSDriver<MobileElement>`

Comment: But still I am getting the same issue . Even after initialized.

Comment: public class applaunch {
 IOSDriver driver;                                                                DesiredCapabilities cap= new DesiredCapabilities(); cap.setCapability("appium-version", "1.14.3");cap.setCapability("app","/Users/manigandan/Downloads/iOrder_UAT_2.2.1.00V.ipa"); // app
cap.setCapability("platformName", "iOS"); cap.setCapability(CapabilityType.VERSION, "8.1.3");                        driver = new IOSDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), cap); driver.findElementByIosUIAutomation(".mainWindow().buttons()[22]").tap(1,250)

Comment: Change `IOSDriver driver;` to `IOSDriver<MobileElement> driver;`

Comment: Working fine. driver.findElement(MobileBy.IosUIAutomation("yourlocator"))